# In referencing a java object, what is the difference between the two?

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java. I have a simple question.

```
public Object getObject() {

//`do something that results to an Object`

return object;

}
```

1st:

```
Object object1 = new Object();
object1 = getObject();
```

2nd:

```
Object object1 = getObject();
```

What is the difference between the two? Which is better to use?

Comment: They both do the same thing. (The first creates an unnecessary object, so you should probably use the second..). You also have a missing semicolon in your first line of code, so it won't compile as-is.

Comment: the first one creates an unnecessary object?

Comment: There is no difference between the 2 except you initialize `object1` in the beginning (and forgot to end the expression with a `;`).

Comment: Let's not get hung up on the missing `;`, folks. It's a clear typo.

Comment: The first one looks like it was written by someone who didn't know what they were doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case, you are first making a new Object and immediately throwing it away on the next line when you replace it with the result of getObject().

If you modify it slightly, you'll see that the two objects are different instances.

```
Object object1 = new Object();
System.out.println(object1);
object1 = getObject();
System.out.println(object1);
```

When you run that, not that the printed value is different. This is because there were two different values assigned to object1.

This is not a pattern you want to be using. All you are doing here is making an object that needs to be garbage collected.

I'm also not sure that case 1 even works. It won't compile, because object is an undefined variable. You would need to change it to `return new Object();` That way the value to return is defined.

Really what you want to do is just say `Object object = new Object();` Adding the getObject function really isn't buying you anything.

Comment: The //`do something that results to an Object` stands for all the required codes in order for it to return an "object" which includes making a new instance. Thank you for your answer. I knew that there's something to do with garbage collection. I'm just not sure.

Comment: Things become a candidate for garbage collection whenever they are no longer referenced. So once you give a new value to object1, the previous value is collected. The compile might actually just optimize it away in this case, sometimes it can do that.

Comment: I believe the right thing to say is  "the previous value might be collected" since it's only a CANDIDATE for garbage collection. It's not a 100% sure if it will be garbage collected. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

They return the same thing (add ";" to the first line of the 1st example :P).